# How to order the contact alphabetically that are fetched from android device using phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile

This is my code to fetch contacts from android device:

```
function onDeviceReady() 
{
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="";  
    options.multiple=true;
    var fields = ["*"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}
function onSuccess(contacts) 
{
    alert('Total Contacts '+contacts.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) 
    {
        if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers.length>0)
        {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+=contacts[i].displayName+"-"+ contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value+"<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to fetch all the contacts but I want them to display alphabetically. Please help me. I also tried with the options.sort but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the returned contacts variable is an array of objects and you want to sort by the displayName property.

Create a compare function:

```
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.displayName< b.displayName)
     return -1;
  if (a.displayName> b.displayName)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

Then call sort() passing in your compare function, before iterating the array:

```
contacts.sort(compare);
```

Comment: it worked but it is showing null in front of the contacts that are saved in google accounts, like say i have a contact with name Naira Rao then it is showing result as 'nullNaira Rao'.. any solution on this.?

Comment: @N.R, is the sort adding the null or is it already in the contacts object?

Comment: and where from these parameters are going to compare function a & b?

Comment: @N.R a nd b are 2 elements from the array being compared (this happens automatically): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort